# TensorflowJS: different shape for output

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow.js

I'm completely new to Tensorflow.

My goal is quite simple: I have a 3d tensor as an input/training value, and I'd like to "map" that to a 1d output tensor.

When running my model, I get an error, that the 1d output tensor can't be assigned to the defined `[5, 5]` shape:

```
const model = tf.sequential({
  layers: [
    tf.layers.dense({
      inputShape: [5, 5],
      units: 32,
      activation: "relu"
    }),
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: "softmax" }),
  ]
});
```

Is it possible to have different shapes for output/input? I want the 3d tensor to be like "groups of numbers" resolve to a single (1d tensor) number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map a high dimensional tensor (superior to 1) to a 1d tensor, a flatten layers needs to be used in between

```
const model = tf.sequential({
  layers: [
    tf.layers.dense({
      inputShape: [5, 5],
      units: 32,
      activation: "relu"
    }),
    tf.layers.flatten(),
    tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: "softmax" }),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Before that answer was given, I already came up with the idea to flatten my array given to `tf.tensor` using the default `Array.flat()` method. Is there any difference to flattening the array manually or using the flatten layer?

Comment: `Array.flat` will flatten a normal js array whereas the model is expecting a flatten tensor

Comment: Yes, but on creation of that tensor, I ran array.flat() before giving the array to the tensor. Will that cause different behaviour than using the flatten layer? (both seemed to work)